# Play-slick postgres: does it automatically create database?

Tags: playframework-2.0, play-slick

I was using in memory DB and i didn't have any issue in needing to pre-create the database.

I have now changed to using postgres as my play-slick database with the below config:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sandbox"
```

It is saying database "sandbox" does not exist when I start the app. Is there anyway that I could make play-slick create the database for me if it doesn't exist? Thanks!